# What to expect after post doc Skype interview

Tags: postdocs

I had a Skype interview from Caltech. The PI told me I'm one among the 6 shortlisted candidates for 1 position and he said to all others too and hence not to have too much expectations. This he told in the beginning of the interview itself. The interview was kind of okay. Most of the Time he was talking about the position and his lab... He also asked if I will be potentially available. I said yes. I told briefly about my interests. He said he'll review applications during vacation.  He said mine was a strong application. Sometimes he responded very positively and sometimes I felt I'm not good enough. He cut call saying goodnight. I wished him a good day( I'm in India) saying that I look forward to talk to him soon to which he responded with smile. I know I'm  overthinking but this is really important to me. Is it worth hoping for a positive reply?

Comment: Can you be more clear about what your question is?

Comment: You need to become patient with your job search. Your best bet is to focus on writing more applications, so that you will avoid wasting your energy by waiting and worrying.

Answer (score 5):

The whole process is unpredictable, and you gain nothing by worrying and second-guessing things. I nailed interviews for jobs I didn't get and got jobs from my worse interviews and everywhere in between. You did your best, you will know the result when it's done.

> Relax!

Answer (score 2):

You should expect that you are 1 of 6 shortlisted candidates.

He didn't say anything glowing that should make you think you are now the only shortlisted candidate. He didn't say anything definitive to warn you are not a fit. There is no good reason to think your position now has changed in any way.

You should be happy to be on a shortlist of six, but not expecting anything. You should assume your chances are about 1/6. To me, that clearly means keep looking for other jobs but remain hopeful. It would be foolish to expect you have a secured position at 1/6. It would also be foolish to expect 1/6 means it's impossible.

There's not much else to advise here except to keep at it and find some things to do that help you relax or feel enjoyment, and then just wait. :)

You should also know you are not just a candidate for a job, you also hope to bring something of value. Therefore, you should consider not just your chances but also whether it's a good spot for you as an individual. Just because you get a job doesn't mean you take it.